# Functions not responding on amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, amazon-ec2, python-requests

In the below code when the URL passed is something of myntra the `request` function is not loading on amazon EC2 instance where as it is loading for other links as amazon, flipkart etc. What can be the possible reason for this. On local everything is working fine!!

```
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    }
    r =  requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    print("request got")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
    print("soup passed")
    json_data = json.loads(soup.select_one("script:nth-of-type(2)").string)
    price = json_data["offers"]["price"]
    print("price got")
    fprice= float(price)
```

Comment: Is it that myntra is not allowing proxy or whatever of ec2 instance

Comment: Some websites block access from the Amazon EC2 range of IP addresses because it is often used for web scraping of prices (which looks like what you are attempting to do). You can test it by logging into the instance and trying to `curl` the URL to see if information is returned. Please note that you should not violate the Terms & Conditions on websites by scraping their content.